# What is the meaning of “There is this guy”?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I’ve seen the phrase “there’s this guy...” a number of times, and in each context it seems to has a different meaning (every time I just guess according to the context!)
Is there any idiomatic meaning to this phrase?!

Answer (score 1):

There's no hidden meaning here, it's literally just expressing the existence of a particular person. I suppose you'd typically hear this at the start of a story about someone interesting. The phrase "this guy" instead of "a guy" helps to focus the attention on the particular individual, who will usually be the subject of the story due to some remarkable characteristic.

"So I go to the store, and there's this guy with no pants on!"